# IE 11 and Edge in Windows 10 doesn't allow to change language preference which are applicable only to the browser

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10 Internet Explorer 11 and Edge does not allow to change Language preference through the browser. The option which is available in Internet Explorer 11 directs to OS Language preference.
Any changes done in control panel for language preference will be applicable to other applications on the machine as well (Maybe after log off or restart).

Is there a way to select language preference only for the browser(Internet Explorer 11 and Edge) in Windows 10? Just like it works in Chrome and Firefox.

Note: Options are still present in Chrome and Firefox, but I need answer for IE11 and Edge.

Answer (score 8):

After searching for the answer to this for quite some time I finally found a way to force the language in IE11.

My system is set to german and I need one website to be in english. 
I found a the following registry key and just tried if it still makes an impact on the language:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International]
"AcceptLanguage"="en-US,de-DE;q=0.9,de;q=0.8"
```

This key sets the order and preference of the accepted languages. There is a [blog from MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/10/17/accept-language-header-for-internet-explorer-7/) that explains what the values mean. It's quite old but still valid. The important part for the purpose of the question is the first part here. In my case "en-US", it will probably be in the language of your system (mine was "de-DE" before, which I changed to have a lower "q" value, which I believe is the preference of a language, higher means more preferred, without "q" means "q=1").

After you change the value restart IE.

I tested it under Windows 10 with IE 11.
Please be advised that that changes the preferred language for all websites you visit with the IE 11.

EDIT: See @Daniel s Answer for a working String if mine doesn't. My guess is: you are looking at a website that has another "en" language than "en-US".

Comment: tried on Microsoft Windows Version 10.0.16299.431 with IE 11.0.65 on a system installed and configured to en-US and registry key AcceptLanguage set to de-DE, restarted IE, could not confirm working - still transmitted en-US in the headers.

Comment: Can confirm: Worked for me in Edge 42, using @Daniel's String value

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't comment to the post from @Surrogard, I want to extend it here since I had the same problem as @dlatikay so I did the following: I changed the language preferences in Google Chrome and looked at the `Accept-Language` header:

```
en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
```

Setting this in `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\International\AcceptLanguage]` works as expected for our Remedy ticket system.